# How can I config Yocto 2.3 emulator in Eclipse?

Tags: centos, eclipse, yocto

I have to configure Yocto 2.3 emulator in Linux Centos 7 eclipse. The problem that I don't the place of directory that I suppose to use based on the link below:

**Yocto guidelines**

Please see the pictures below:

eclipse configuration Centos 7

[image]

What is the directory regarding my files.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for the Yocto project is very good, make sure you checkit:

https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/current/adt-manual/adt-manual.html#mars-configuring-the-eclipse-yocto-plug-in

http://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/latest/mega-manual/mega-manual.html

The folder it's asking for is the location of the toolchain. If you are starting, I would recommend to install it from the script. 
http://downloads.yoctoproject.org/releases/yocto/yocto-2.3/toolchain/

The default location is `/opt/poky/2.3`. If you accept that, your settings for the plugin will be:

- Select Standalone pre-built toolchain
- Toolchain Root Location: /opt/poky/2.3
- Sysroot Location: /opt/poky/2.3/sysroots
- Target Architecture: armvahf-neon-poky-linux-genueabi (this is the one I use, it can change for you depending of the toolchain that you install)

Comment: Thanks, the yocto is installed in my VM of Centos 7. The problem that I don't find the default directory and `/opt/`

Comment: The poky folder contains all the necessary contents, but I cannot find the toolchain directory. How can I do this?

Comment: Also, how can I install SDK. I used the command `runqemu` but does not work to install it in `/poky` folder.

Comment: @YAcaCsh I think you still have some Yocto concepts unclear. Yocto is powerful and well documented but it takes time to learn. I would read the getting started guide if you haven't already. The poky folder that you install with metadata and you use to compile and OS is different to the /opt/poky that you create when you install the toolchain with the script.

Comment: thank you, I got your point, but I don't know exactly how to install the SDK. I followed the SDK installation but the problem that I tried to run script in Centos7 and still not working.

Comment: http://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/current/sdk-manual/sdk-manual.html I followed 3.2. for installing the SDK, but no working.

Comment: http://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/current/sdk-manual/sdk-manual.html I followed 3.2. for installing the SDK, but no working. For Example: how can I run this:      poky-glibc-x86_64-core-image-sato-i586-toolchain-2.3.sh. Is it under POKY folder or?